# non-static variable reference from a static context (Java)

Tags: java

I've searched for this problem but still not getting any solution.

I declared this simple program:

```
public class Test{
  public abstract class Person {
      public void talk(){
        System.out.print("I am a person");
      }
      public abstract void display();
  }

  public class Student extends Person {
    public void talk(){
        System.out.println("I am a student");
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Nice to meet you");
        super.talk();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.display();
  }
}
```

but it keeps giving me the error :

error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

```
    Student s = new Student();
```

I've always been declaring objects that way! I don't know what's happening today.

I need to understand what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Other than the `main` method, there seem to be no static method, nor the usage of the `this` keyword. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: it complains about a variable 'this', which you don't have, you also don't use the keyword this, so, make sure your file is saved, and try again

Comment: Yes I am. I don't know what am I doing wrong. :S

Comment: how do you compile and run this programm?

Comment: I'll create a new project file and try to copy the code there

Comment: The problems is that Person and Student are declared inside the class Test. Just put them aside and it will work.

Comment: Still same error, I'm working on TextPad!

Comment: you can only have one public class inside a java file.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle now it gave me this message: class Person is public, should be declared in a file named Person.java . should I also separate it in another file?

Comment: @SaifBadran: either yes, or it shouldn't be a public class

Comment: @SaifBadran Declare each class in its own .java file : Person.java and Student.java

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle : you meant to tag the OP ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I declared each class in it's own and it worked properly. But I have a question is there's any other way to make classes in the same file? thanks!

Comment: @SaifBadran: unless they should not be used except for in combination, or are very closely bound, it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: @SaifBadran Yes, you can add the keyword `static` : `public static class Student` but I recommend creating a file apart. By declaring them in the same class, you actually made `Student` and `Person` inner-class of class `Test` and it has its consequences that you need to understand (I upvoted Andy Turner 's answer because he explains it well).

Comment: Thank you I got it clear now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare inner classes:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
  }

  void doSomething() {}
}
```

there is an implicit reference to an instance of the `Outer` class held by each instance of `Inner`. This means that you can write the following in the inner class to refer to the outer instance:

```
Outer.this.doSomething();
```

Actually, you can often write simply `doSomething()` - you only need the `Outer.this` if the inner class also has a method called `doSomething()`, and you need to disambiguate.

The long and short of this is that you actually need an instance of `Outer` to create an instance of `Inner`:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

If you don't actually need to refer to the instance of `Outer` inside `Inner` (e.g. you never need to call `doSomething()`), the simplest solution is just to make the inner class `static`:

```
class Outer {
  static class Inner {}

  void doSomething();
}
```

In fact, I would recommend that you *always* make you inner classes static, unless you *really* need them to be non-static.

Comment: Perfect answer @Andy

Comment: Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner(); clears everything,,In order to have an instance of inner class you need the instance of outer class

Answer (score 1):

make your Person and Student Classes static

OR

Create Test Object first to create Student object in main method.

`Student s = new Test().new Student();`

Reason: As Person/Student classes are non static, they can't exist without Test Object. So either those classes should be static or Test() should be created first to create Student.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by Test object?

Comment: Yes I got the idea now. but it's just easier to separate the files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove person and student from your Test class:

```
public abstract class Person { 
    public void talk(){ 
        System.out.print("I am a person"); 
    }
    public abstract void display();
} 

public class Student extends Person    { 
    public void talk(){ 
        System.out.println("I am a student"); 
    }     
    public void display(){ 
        System.out.println("Nice to meet you");
        super.talk(); 
    } 
}

public class Test{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Student s = new Student();    
        s.display(); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works all fine:

```
     abstract class Person {
        public void talk(){
            System.out.print("I am a person");
        }
        public abstract void display();
    }

     class Student extends Person {
         public void talk() {
             System.out.println("I am a student");
         }

         public void display() {
             System.out.println("Nice to meet you");
             super.talk();
         }
     }

    public class Test {


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.display();
        }
    }
```